# Dictionary Size and Compression Method

Tags: compression, archiving

I have knowledge about archiving, since I already try it so many times in a basic way just right click and add to archive then press ok, but it is my first time to modify it using the settings.

I want to store the folder in an archive without compressing it and retain its original size and everything. However, if I select store option, there is a dictionary size. What is that?
[A store compression method and a bunch of dictionary size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU6AC.png)

I try it to myself to know the results:

[This is a store and 64kb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oORKS.png)

[This is a store and 4096kb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fOoO.png)

I am a little bit confuse about the sizes. Is there a single piece of information that leads into a loss of data in a long run?

That is why I decided to archive a folder without compressing it, so that there is no loss of data and I can upload it on the internet in an efficient way. However, there is a dictionary size which I am uncertain of.

Comment: It doesn't *really* answer your question directly but if you want to store something without compressing it, make it a `tar` ball.  That's exactly what `tar` does.  When you see thingy.tar.gz .. thats a tar ball that has been compressed with gzip compression.  If you are a windows guy, 7zip makes nice tar balls.. WSL.. minGW.. cygwin all do a nice job making tar archives using the `tar` utility directly.